# Regex pattern - ignore whitespace, line breaks, tabs etc

Tags: regex, perl, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I have something like this:

```
<div class="wp-caption">
    <a href="https://">
        <img src="https://" alt="blabla">
    </a>
</div>
```

And I want to replace it with

```
<figure>
    <a href="https://">
        <img src="https://" alt="blabla">
    </a>
</figure>
```

I'm using regex pattern like this:
Search for `<div class="wp-caption">(.*)</div>`
Replace `<figure>(.*)</figure>`

Which works fine, but not when there are line breaks, spaces, tabs or some other formatting inside, how can I tell to ignore it?

I'm using Sublime Text.. what is using Perl style for expressions.

Comment: add `s` modifier.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How is using like this in Perl?

```
s/<div class="wp-caption">(.*?)<\/div>/<figure>$1<\/figure>/sg
```

- regex replacement operation with `s///`
- To avoid greedy match, using `?` with `.*`
- The captured string with `(.*?)` is stored in variable $1.
- `/` inside regex can be escaped with `\` (backslash).
- `s` option means single line mode which ignores newlines.
- `g` option means global match (all matches are processed).

Comment: For those arriving here to do this in other contexts, note that if you are doing this to a file of text, the text must be accumulated into a single string before this will work, e.g. `$content = join('',<>);$content =~ s/<div class="wp-caption">(.*?)<\/div>/<figure>$1<\/figure>/sg;`  And don't chomp the newlines.

Answer (score 4):

Additionally to [Bohemian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32568057/710099)'s answer if you don't want to use inline flags, then you can use a regex trick like this:

```
<div class="wp-caption">([\s\S]*?)</div>
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

With the substitution string:

```
<figure>$1</figure>
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/tM4xE4/1)**

[image]

The trick is using `[\s\S]`, meaning you will match spaces and non spaces multiple times (ie. everything).

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
Find: (?s)<div class="wp-caption">(.*?)</div>
Replace: <figure>\1</figure>
```

The trick here is `(?s)` which makes dot match newlines, and `(.*?)` to capture *non-greedily* (will stop consuming at the next `</div>`) the contents of the `<div>` tag.

`\1` is a *back reference* to the captured group 1.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `dotall` modifier as follows:

```
(?s)<div[^>]+>(.*?)</div>
```

and replace with:

```
<figure>$1</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, at least for your example:

```
s/div(\sclass="wp-caption")?/figure$1/g;
```

Answer (score 0):

On sublime Ctrl+f(Grep)

Find:

```
<div[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)</div>
```

Replace:

```
<figure>\1</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will work

```
$variable =~ s!<div(?:\s+[^<>)?)?>(.*?)</div>!
           my $div_cont = $1;
           "<figure>".$div_cont."</figure>";
           !sge;
```